# Assign enum value to property in Obj-C

Tags: objective-c, swift, enums

I have the following code in Swift. How would I convert this to Objective-C? (Yes, Swift to Objective-C) ;)

```
class PopAnimator: NSObject, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {

    enum PopTransitionMode: Int {
        case Present, Dismiss
    }

    var transitionMode: PopTransitionMode = .Present

}
```

I've tried the following in Obj-C, am not sure how to assign a value type of `PopTransitionMode` to my property.

```
// .h
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PopTransitionMode) {
    Present,
    Dismiss
};
@interface PopAnimator : NSObject <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>
@property (nonatomic, assign) PopTransitionMode transitionMode;
@end


// .m
@implementation PopAnimator

-(id)init {

   if (self = [super init]) {

       _transitionMode = ???

   }


   return self;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use the enumerated values.  With better naming, enum like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, PopTransitionMode) {
    PopTransitionModePresent,
    PopTransitionModeDismiss
};
```

Init like this:

```
// if the initializer takes a param
- (id)initWithTransitionMode:(PopTransitionMode)transitionMode {
    self = [self init];
    if (self) {
        _transitionMode = transitionMode;
    }
   return self;
}

// OR, if the initializer hard-codes a param
- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _transitionMode = PopTransitionModeDismiss;
    }
   return self;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @danh! I was trying to declare it as `_transitionMode = .Dismiss` and forgot that enum dot syntax is unavailable in Obj-C.